# Given a position in matrix [i, j], find the block it belongs to

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, matrix

Well, I am dealing with sudoku solving algorithm and generation but stuck at rather simple task. I have made the check, whether a number is really fit in the position row-wise and column-wise. But what it is driving me mad is block check, ie, whether the number is really fit in the 3x3 block.

It must be simple enough but I can't really arrive at the solution. In short, I want to know the 3x3 block to which a position in matrix belongs. Here are some of the assert cases. The block no, row no and col no indexing starts from 0.

```
assert("x( 0, 8 ) === 2"); 
assert("x( 8, 8 ) === 8"); 
assert("x( 3, 3 ) === 4"); 
assert("x( 3, 7 ) === 5"); 
assert("x( 7, 1 ) === 6");
```

`x( i , j )` returns the block number where `i` = row and `j` = col.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isn't it just:

```
block = 3 * (i / 3) + (j / 3)
```

(assumes integer operations).

I would code a check, something like this (in pseudo C++)

```
// row = row to check
// col = column to check
// checkNum = number we are thinking of inserting
bool check(int row, int col, int checkNum)
{
    int blockRow = 3 * (row/3);
    int blockCol = 3 * (col/3);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i++)
    {
        if(grid[row][i] == checkNum) return false; // number exists in the row.
        if(grid[i][col] == checkNum) return false; // number exists in the col.
        if(grid[blockRow + i/3][blockCol + i%3] == checkNum) return false; // number exists in the block.
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sudoku solver in javascript. Taken from [DSSudokuSolver](https://github.com/dhilipsiva/dssudokusolver/blob/master/static/app.js), that I created.
The CleanElements function does something similar to what you are asking for.

```
CleanElements = function(comp_ary, Qsudoku){
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){
            /*if(Qsudoku[i][j] != ""){
                comp_ary[i][j]=[];
            }*/
            for(k=0; k<9; k++){
                i_index = comp_ary[i][k].indexOf(Qsudoku[i][j]);
                if(i_index != -1){
                    comp_ary[i][k].splice(i_index, 1);
                }
                j_index = comp_ary[k][j].indexOf(Qsudoku[i][j]);
                if(j_index != -1){
                    comp_ary[k][j].splice(j_index, 1);
                }
            }
            if(i < 3){
                i_min = 0;
                i_max = 2;
            }
            else if(i < 6){
                i_min = 3;
                i_max = 5;
            }
            else{
                i_min = 6;
                i_max = 8;
            }

            if(j < 3){
                j_min = 0;
                j_max = 2;
            }
            else if(j < 6){
                j_min = 3;
                j_max = 5;
            }
            else{
                j_min = 6;
                j_max = 8;
            }

            for(i_box=i_min; i_box<=i_max; i_box++){
                for(j_box=j_min; j_box<=j_max; j_box++){
                    index = comp_ary[i_box][j_box].indexOf(Qsudoku[i][j]);
                    if(index != -1){
                        comp_ary[i_box][j_box].splice(index, 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return comp_ary;
}

FindElements = function(comp_ary, Qsudoku){
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){
            if(comp_ary[i][j].length == 1){
                if (Qsudoku[i][j] == ""){
                    Qsudoku[i][j] = comp_ary[i][j][0];
                    comp_ary[i][j] = [];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return Qsudoku;
}

IsThereNullElement = function(Qsudoku){
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){
            if(Qsudoku[i][j] == ""){
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

InitEmptyArray = function(){
    empty_ary = Array();
    for(i=0; i<9; i++){
        empty_ary[i] = Array();
        for(j=0; j<9; j++){
            empty_ary[i][j] = Array();
            for(k=0; k<9; k++){
                empty_ary[i][j][k] = (k+1).toString();
            }
        }
    }
    return empty_ary;
}

DSSolve = function(Qsudoku){
    comp_ary = InitEmptyArray(); //Complementary Array
    window.comp_ary_old = comp_ary;
    IterationMax = 5000;

    while(true){
        IterationMax -= 1;
        comp_ary = CleanElements(comp_ary, Qsudoku);
        console.log(comp_ary);

        if(window.comp_ary_old == comp_ary){
            //implement this.
        }
        else{
            window.comp_ary_old = comp_ary;
        }

        Qsudoku = FindElements(comp_ary, Qsudoku);
        //console.log(Qsudoku);

        if(IsThereNullElement(Qsudoku)){
            return Qsudoku;
        }

        if(IterationMax == 0){
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```